# Private WAF on reserved instance IBM API Connect

Tags: apiconnect, web-application-firewall

We need to protect our reserved instance of IBM API Connect that we have in the Cloud with a WAF of our own company and we do not know if this is possible and the steps to perform or if it is only possible with a WAF of IBM's own cloud.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I'm going to assume you're asking primarily about the DataPower API Gateway.

You can either deploy your own gateway in an environment of your choosing (i.e. you're managing it) or leverage the one that IBM provides to you by default.

If you deploy your own, then you control the networking and adding your own WAF is relatively straightforward.

If you use an IBM-managed gateway, then a little creativity is required. You would likely need to set up a Mutual TLS contract between your WAF and the Gateway. You'd terminate the incoming TLS connection at the WAF (e.g. Cloudflare) and then re-encrypt the traffic from the WAF to the Gateway using the client certificate exchange. You'd potentially need to apply a Mutual TLS-enforcing profile to each deployed API on the Gateway. In this scenario, no client can call an API on your gateway without the proper TLS client key/certificate in hand.

You may want to open a support ticket for further/deeper assistance on this topic.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your response.

we have a reserved instance of API Connect in IBM cloud (managed by them), so yes, we are talking about Datapower API Gateway in V5 managed by IBM, where what we need to protect with our WAF is only the developer's portals, not the consumption of the APIs... although from your answer I see that it is possible to do it for the consumption of the APIs... I have doubts if it would be possible for the portals.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's theoretically possible with the portals, but maybe somewhat tricky. Perhaps you could point your domain name at your WAF and proxy back to the portal on a different domain. The portal's native DNS might still be reachable, but most of your traffic would flow through the WAF. It's worth opening a support ticket for further exploration.